# Linux mv with matched file names

Tags: linux

I want to move in a specific folder all the files matching a simple pattern but i really don't know how; this is what i tried:

```
mv *.o obj/*.o
```

don't laugh at me, i'm not really handy with linux.

p.s i don't know if it's relevant, but the mv is actually inside a makefile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do:

```
mv *.o obj/
```

The trailing `/` is not strictly necessary, but I would recommend it - the effect is to have it error out if `obj` is not a directory (or does not exist) and there is only one `.o` file; otherwise, it would rename that one `.o` file to `obj`, possibly overwriting the pre-existing `obj`.

Comment: I got into the habit of typing `dir/.` rather than just `dir/`, because some old version of Solaris would actually accept a trailing `/` on a (non-directory) file name.  For example, `cat /etc/motd/` would actually work.  I don't think any modern systems do this (Solaris 9 doesn't).